# How to insert values in one column? c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 foreach (string value in data1)
 {         
     var match = Regex.Match(value, @"(?<Number>\d+)(?<Text>.*)");
     var number = match.Groups["Number"].Value;
     var text = match.Groups["Text"].Value;
     string result2 = string.Format("{0}", text);
     data.Rows.Add(result2);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
 }
```

This code will add the data to my first column. How do i fix it to make that data to be added to the second column instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you need move the line of binding datasource out of the loop block firstly,

```
foreach (string value in data1)
{

    var match = Regex.Match(value, @"(?<Number>\d+)(?<Text>.*)");
    var number = match.Groups["Number"].Value;
    var text = match.Groups["Text"].Value;
    string result2 = string.Format("{0}", text);
    data.Rows.Add(result2);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataColumn Col   = datatable.Columns.Add("Column Name", typeof(Boolean));

Col.SetOrdinal(0);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me! I'm trying to add rows in one column.

Comment: "typeof(Boolean)" instead of "System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")" will be read better

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow newRow = data.NewRow();

newRow["Text"] = text; //if the column name is Text 

data.Rows.Add(newRow);
```